Auto Text Size issue in jetpack compose
in my app i have an id card composable which displays id card but on different screens the proportions are messed up because of variation in dpi so i wanted to have a text whose bounds are fixed and it should auto decide the text size to fit i looked up on google got some code which looks fine but somehow doesnt work
@Composable
fun AutoSizeText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    style: TextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
    color: Color,
) {
    var reSized by remember{
        mutableStateOf(style)
    }
    var shouldDraw by remember{
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    if(!shouldDraw) reSized = reSized.copy(fontSize = 50.sp)
    Text(
        text = text,
        color = color,
        modifier = modifier.border(color = Color.Green,width = 1.dp).drawWithContent {
            if(shouldDraw) drawContent()
        },
        softWrap = false,
        maxLines = 1,
        style = reSized,
        onTextLayout = {
            if(it.didOverflowHeight or it.didOverflowWidth){
                reSized = reSized.copy(fontSize = reSized.fontSize * 0.999f)
            }else{
                shouldDraw = true
            }
        }
    )
}

Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
    AutoSizeText(modifier = Modifier.height(36.dp),text = "${pass.id}", color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer)
    AutoSizeText(modifier = Modifier.height(36.dp),text = pass.purpose, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer)
    Image(modifier = Modifier.size(36.dp), painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_logo), contentDescription = "logo", colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer))
}


as shown in the photo the green border is the size of the text which has fixed height of 36.dp and its width is automatic. the AutoTextSize is in a row.
the problem is the text is shrinking way to much as you can see it can clearly take more width and fit inside but it doesnt.
the first empty box never shows any text even though it has a 1 digit text.
EDIT:
this is how it should actually be


It is quite unclear what you want to achieve. Could you please provide an example?

@Steyrix i have edited my question to include what it should look like without problem.

To me it looks like the height of the text on the second texture is bigger than on the first one. So maybe 36 dp. height is not enough? I suggest not using some kind of autosizing. To me it looks like your problem can be solved using alignment  parameter and choosing reasonable sp for the text

@Steyrix both image has same height of text the 2nd image has no vertical padding on text which is default behavior but somehow when i use the AutoTextSize it has some vertical padding. i have to use auto sizing because in my use case the text size has to be proportional to the card size
